# Unsatisfiable Cores in Z3 Python

Tags: z3, z3py

I am working with the Python API of Z3 in an attempt to include support for it in a research tool that I am writing. I have a question regarding extracting the unsatisfiable core using the Python interface.

I have the following simple query:

```
(set-option :produce-unsat-cores true)
(assert (! (not (= (_ bv0 32) (_ bv0 32))) :named __constraint0))
(check-sat)
(get-unsat-core)
(exit)
```

Running this query through the z3 executable (for **Z3 4.1**), I receive the expected result:

```
unsat
(__constraint0)
```

For **Z3 4.3**, I obtain a segmentation fault:

```
unsat
Segmentation fault
```

That isn't the main question, although that was an intriguing observation. I then modified the query (inside a file) as

```
(assert (! (not (= (_ bv0 32) (_ bv0 32))) :named __constraint0))
(exit)
```

Using a file handler, I passed the contents of this file (in a variable `queryStr') to the following Python code:

```
import z3
...
solver = z3.Solver()
solver.reset()
solver.add(z3.parse_smt2_string(queryStr))
querySatResult = solver.check()
if querySatResult == z3.sat:
    ...
elif querySatResult == z3.unsat:
    print solver.unsat_core()
```

I receive the empty list from the `unsat_core' function: []. Am I using this function incorrectly? The docstring for the function suggests that I should instead be doing something similar to

```
solver.add(z3.Implies(p1, z3.Not(0 == 0)))
```

However, I was wondering if it were still possible to use the query as is, since it conforms to SMT-LIB v2.0 standards (I believe), and whether I was missing something obvious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The crash you observed has been fixed, and the fix will be available in the next release. If you try the "unstable" (work-in-progress) branch, you should get the expected behavior.
You can retrieve the unstable branch using

```
git clone https://git01.codeplex.com/z3 -b unstable
```

The API `parse_smt2_string` provides only basic support for parsing formulas in SMT 2.0 format. It does not keep the annotations `:named`. We will address this and other limitations in future versions. In the meantime, we should use "answer literals" such as `p1` and assertions of the form:

```
solver.add(z3.Implies(p1, z3.Not(0 == 0)))
```

In the "unstable" branch, we also support the following new API. It "simulates" the `:named` assertions used in the SMT 2.0 standard.

```
def assert_and_track(self, a, p):
    """Assert constraint `a` and track it in the unsat core using the Boolean constant `p`.

    If `p` is a string, it will be automatically converted into a Boolean constant.

    >>> x = Int('x')
    >>> p3 = Bool('p3')
    >>> s = Solver()
    >>> s.set(unsat_core=True)
    >>> s.assert_and_track(x > 0,  'p1')
    >>> s.assert_and_track(x != 1, 'p2')
    >>> s.assert_and_track(x < 0,  p3)
    >>> print(s.check())
    unsat
    >>> c = s.unsat_core()
    >>> len(c)
    2
    >>> Bool('p1') in c
    True
    >>> Bool('p2') in c
    False
    >>> p3 in c
    True
    """
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the incredibly quick and detailed response, Leonardo. I will be going with the first suggested approach (with `answer literals') for now.