# Microsoft Z3 naming assertions

Tags: assert, z3, named

I need to name some assertions im my z3 model so that it is able to generate unsat cores.

I can do this manually like this:

```
(assert (! (assertion) :named x))
```

I just need to do it using the .NET API directly.

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Z3 does not support this directly through the .NET API. Instead, a Boolean constant should be created (the name, e.g., `x`), which can then be used to assert conditional constraints, e.g.,

```
solver.AssertAndTrack(constraint, x);
```

The constraint is then named `x` and this constant is used to refer to it in the unsat cores.
For an example in Python, see also this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560745/unsatisfiable-cores-in-z3-python); the strategy is the same in the .NET API, only the function names differ slightly.

Comment: Christoph: the method exists and calling it works fine. However, when unsat, still no unsat-core is generated

Comment: I suppose you didn't enable unsat core generation then. Note that MkGoal takes Boolean parameters that enable models, unsat cores, or proofs. Also, the global option unsat_core should be enabled.

Comment: Christoph: the option is enabled. the problem is lies with the JAVA API itself, it is a bit erratic. Sometimes it generates unsatcore, and sometimes it doesn't

Comment: I see. Not sure how this could come about. Would you have an example that shows this erratic behavior?