# Z3 - how assumptions works

Tags: z3, z3py

I have the following code in Z3py

```
    import z3
    x = z3.BitVec('x', 32)
    a = z3.BitVec('a', 32)
    solver=z3.Solver()
    solver.set(unsat_core=True)
    d=z3.Bool('d')
    solver.assert_and_track(x!=a,d)
    solver.add(x==a)
    print solver.check(d)
    print solver.check(z3.Not(d))
```

I would expect it to print `unsat` and `sat`. However it prints always `unsat`. Should the call `solver.check(z3.Not(d))` effectively disable the assertion `x!=a`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`assert_and_track` simply associates the answer-literal `d` with the formula `x!=a` in your example. Since the context contains `x==a` and `x!=a` at the same time, it is `unsat`. No assumptions will make it satisfiable.

But I do agree that this is very confusing. I think the issue goes back to the fact that `assert_and_track` is *not* really intended for what you are trying to do, but merely to make unsat-core-extraction possible. See the discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14565535/936310

To really achieve what you want, simply assert the implication yourself. That is, use:

```
solver.add(Implies(d, x!=a))
```

For instance, the following script:

```
from z3 import *

x = z3.BitVec('x', 32)
a = z3.BitVec('a', 32)

solver=z3.Solver()
solver.set(unsat_core=True)
d=z3.Bool('d')

solver.add(Implies(d, x!=a))
solver.add(x==a)

print solver.check(d)
print solver.unsat_core()
print solver.check(z3.Not(d))
print solver.model()
```

produces:

```
unsat
[d]
sat
[a = 0, d = False, x = 0]
```

which is what you are trying to achieve, I believe.

Comment: Thanks this is what I wanted to do, I was confused by the pretty print of the check that was showing an implication using assert_and_track.

Comment: If the pretty-print of the solver is showing an `Implies`, then that is indeed troubling. Perhaps it's just a rendering issue, or maybe something deeper. You might want to file a z3 ticket at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues  to seek some clarification from the developers.

Comment: Yes I confirm that on my systems it does show an Implies, using solver.sexpr(). I will try to fill an issue and see why there is this behaviour. Many thanks again for your time.